# Calculate the average of elements in a matrix that correspond to a value in a separate matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a 333 x 333 adjacency matrix which consists of values that I would like to average according to the identity of each cell, which is defined in a separate 333x1 vector. There are a total of 13 different groups defined in the second vector, so ideally, I'd be able to calculate a new 13 x 13 matrix in which each cell contained the average value of the corresponding values from the larger matrix.

matrix_1: 333 x 333 --> contains values for each pairwise interaction

vector_2: 333 x 1 --> contains the identity (range: 1 - 13) for each of the elements in matrix_1 (elements are the same in both the rows and columns)

ideal output = matrix_2: 13 x 13 --> contains values in each cell which reflect the mean score for all examples of the specific identity comparison.

e.g. matrix_2(1,1) --> should contain mean score of all 1 to 1 values from matrix_1

e.g. matrix_2(1,2) --> should contain mean score of all 1 to 2 values (and 2 to 1 values) from matrix_1

Thanks in advance

Mac

Comment: So this is a upper/lower/symmetric matrix?

Comment: yes, it is a symmetric matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain from your description, but I guess you want:

```
[I,J] = ndgrid(V);
out = accumarray([I(:),J(:)], M(:), [], @mean);
```

Comment: Looks like you are getting into `accumarray` lately :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo: Once I learned from one of your answers a few weeks ago, that this beauty can output the generated subsets via cells, I am finally lost in her beautiful brown eyes and want to make little `accum`- and `array`-babies with her!

Comment: @knedlsepp Hahaha. Ok. But leave `bsxfun` alone, or else... :-D

Comment: @LuisMendo: That one is already married to Divakar from what I could tell. ;-)

Comment: @knedlsepp Don't tell me that. You broke my heart

Comment: Anything from MATLAB's morphology library is mine!

Comment: @rayryeng: You are [correct](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/273107)! (Searching for `morph`)

Comment: @knedlsepp - ahahah 17 answers! nice!

Comment: @LuisMendo: I'm sorry to tell you that he has [the bigger crush](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/273107/)...

Comment: One of these days I have to learn how to use that data explorer!

Comment: @knedlsepp - I'm the king of `meshgrid`!

Comment: @rayryeng: Why would you use `meshgrid`, when there's `ndgrid`? :-P

Comment: `meshgrid` I use for images.  `ndgrid` is used when you want to plot things.  The `X` and `Y` convention in `meshgrid` is akin to the coordinate system for images, which is why I like using it. Of course `ndgrid` is better (or actually you can only use `ndgrid`...) for dimensions higher than 3.

Comment: @rayryeng: Oh! Nearly any case where I had to choose, `ndgrid` was the logical choice. Seems like I don't do enough image processing; didn't know `meshgrid` was actually the way to go there!

Comment: @knedlsepp - oh :) hehe.  Well partly I'm biased to `meshgrid` because I've used it for such a long time that I wasn't aware of `ndgrid`'s existence until I started answering here.  The things you learn on this website eh?  Yeah there are times when I can't get an answer for a MATLAB question in when really good answers such as what you provide, or Luis, or Divakar etc. are made, so I venture into the image processing and OpenCV tags to get my rep points :P BTW, good answer here! Forgot to upvote.